# How to prevent further execution of class if something fails in constructor

Tags: php, oop, constructor

How to prevent further execution of class if something fails in constructor.

```
........Worker.php..............
class Worker {

    public function __construct() {

        try {               
            $this->pheanstalk   = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            logFatal('Pheanstalk: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    .............
    .............
    .............
    .............
}
```

.

```
............processing.php..........
require_once ROOTPATH.'worker.php';

$worker = new worker();
$worker -> put($Data);
.............
.............
.............
.............
```

Now if the try block fails in the constructor i dont want to execute put() but rest of code should continue in processing.php

new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1'); throws a exception which is caught by catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best solution is to catch the exception outside your class. Not only can you skip the `put`, logging errors is also not really the responsibility of that class anyway. Oh and Unit testing is easier too!

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        if ($somethingFails === true)
           throw new Exception();
    }
}

try {
    $instance = new SomeClass();
    $instance->put();
} catch (Exception $exception) { 
    // Handle here
    logFatal('Pheanstalk: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

If it's another piece of application throwing the exception, and your constructor is wrapped around it. Consider catching the exception, and then throwing your own.

Comment: new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1'); throws a exception which is caught by catch currently so what change u want me to do

Comment: I've added some more explanation at the bottom of my post. If your class is a wrapper around that, I'd catch and throw my own exception. And still follow the initial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you throw an exception in the constructor?
See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php